# Send emails to multiple recipients from DB zend 2

Tags: database, model-view-controller, zend-framework2

i wan't to send the same mail to multiple recipients retreived from database, using zend framework 2. With my solution i can only send email to the first row on my database, and i do not no what's the problem exactly.
This is my action in the indexController:

```
    public function eventdetailsAction() {
    $id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
    $this->layout()->setVariable('lang', $this->params()->fromRoute('lang',     'en_US'));
    $this->layout()->setVariable('action', $this->params()->fromRoute('action', 'index'));
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $aPost = $request->getPost();
    if (isset($aPost['invitUser'])) {

        $user = new Container('user');
        $db = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('db1');

        if (!$user->offsetExists('id')) {
            $idconnected = '0';
        } else {

            $user = new Container('user');
            $db = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('db1');

            if (!$user->offsetExists('id')) {
                $idconnected = '0';
            } else {

                $idconnected = $user->offsetGet('id');
                $mail = $db->query("SELECT * FROM user")->execute()->current();
                print_r($mail);
                exit();
                $message = new Message();
                foreach ($mail as $recip) {
                    $message->addTo($recip)
                            ->addFrom('xxxxx@gmail.com')
                            ->setSubject('Invitation for the event : Event Latino');
                }

                // Setup SMTP transport using LOGIN authentication
                $transport = new SmtpTransport();
                $options = new SmtpOptions(array(
                    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
                    'connection_class' => 'login',
                    'connection_config' => array(
                        'ssl' => 'tls',
                        'username' => 'xxxxx@gmail.com',
                        'password' => 'xxxxxx'
                    ),
                    'port' => 587,
                ));

                $html = new MimePart('<b>Invitation for the event: Latin Night, orgonized by Mr. Jony Cornillon. Date : 06/04/2015</b>');
                $html->type = "text/html";

                $body = new MimeMessage();
                $body->addPart($html);
                //$body->setParts(array($html));

                $message->setBody($body);

                $transport->setOptions($options);
                $transport->send($message);
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

And also when i put `printr($mail); exit();` to show the result, only the first line will be displayed on the page. Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

In the line below you are executing the query, and then obtaining the `current()` record from the result set the `execute()` call returned. That will always give you the first record in the result set.

```
$mail = $db->query("SELECT * FROM user")->execute()->current();
```

Change that to

```
$mail = $db->query("SELECT * FROM user")->execute();
```

and you should be able to iterate over the result set as expected.

Comment: Hi Crips, i tried as you said but each time no results.i tried also with `$mail = $db->query("SELECT email FROM user ")->execute();
  print_r($mail); exit();`

Comment: This is the code diplayed on my page `Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Result Object ( [statementMode:protected] => forward [resource:protected] => PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT email FROM user ) [options:protected] => [currentComplete:protected] => [currentData:protected] => [position:protected] => -1 [generatedValue:protected] => 0 [rowCount:protected] => )`

Comment: It would appear your query didn't return any records judging by the dump of the result object, maybe start by finding out why that is

Comment: Hello Crip, please can you show my answer above, and tell me about the wrong. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

i find another solution and i can succefully diplay all emails from database with  `print_r`. However now when i put the resultset on the `message->addTo()`, an error will diplay. This is my new code

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user";
                $statement = $db->query($sql);
                $res = $statement->execute();

                if ($res instanceof ResultInterface && $res->isQueryResult()) {
                    $resultSet = new ResultSet;
                    $resultSet->initialize($res);

                    $message = new Message();
                    foreach ($resultSet as $row) {
                        echo $row->email . PHP_EOL;
                        $message->addTo($row->email)
                                ->addTo('xxxxx@hotmail.com', 'eee@web.com')
                                ->addFrom('xxxxx@gmail.com')
                                ->setSubject('Invitation for the event : Event Latino');
                    }
```

Any help please. Thanks.