# Send emails to multiple recipients zend 2

Tags: database, model-view-controller, zend-framework2, zend-mail

i wan't to send the same mail to multiple recipients retreived from database, using zend framework 2. With my solution i can only display all emails from database but i can't send mails to them. I do not no what's the problem exactly. This is my action in the indexController:

```
    public function eventdetailsAction() { 
$id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0); 
$this->layout()->setVariable('lang', $this->params()->fromRoute('lang',     'en_US')); 
$this->layout()->setVariable('action', $this->params()->fromRoute('action', 'index')); 
$request = $this->getRequest(); 
$aPost = $request->getPost(); 
if (isset($aPost['invitUser'])) { 

    $user = new Container('user'); 
    $db = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('db1'); 

    if (!$user->offsetExists('id')) { 
        $idconnected = '0'; 
    } else { 

        $user = new Container('user'); 
        $db = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('db1'); 

        if (!$user->offsetExists('id')) { 
            $idconnected = '0'; 
        } else { 

            $idconnected = $user->offsetGet('id'); 

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM user"; 
            $statement = $db->query($sql); 
            $res = $statement->execute(); 

            if ($res instanceof ResultInterface && $res->isQueryResult()) { 
                $resultSet = new ResultSet; 
                $resultSet->initialize($res); 

                $message = new Message(); 
                foreach ($resultSet as $row) { 
                    echo $row->email . PHP_EOL; 
                    $message->addTo($row->email) 
                            ->addTo('xxxxx@hotmail.com', 'eee@web.com') 
                            ->addFrom('xxxxx@gmail.com') 
                            ->setSubject('Invitation for the event : Event Latino'); 
                } 

            // Setup SMTP transport using LOGIN authentication 
            $transport = new SmtpTransport(); 
            $options = new SmtpOptions(array( 
                'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com', 
                'connection_class' => 'login', 
                'connection_config' => array( 
                    'ssl' => 'tls', 
                    'username' => 'xxxxx@gmail.com', 
                    'password' => 'xxxxxx' 
                ), 
                'port' => 587, 
            )); 

            $html = new MimePart('Invitation for the event: Latin Night, orgonized by Mr. Jony Cornillon. Date : 06/04/2015'); 
            $html->type = "text/html"; 

            $body = new MimeMessage(); 
            $body->addPart($html); 
            //$body->setParts(array($html)); 

            $message->setBody($body); 

            $transport->setOptions($options); 
            $transport->send($message); 
        } 
    } 
} 
}
```

And this is the error displayed each time:

```
5.1.2 We weren't able to find the recipient domain. Please check for any 
5.1.2 spelling errors, and make sure you didn't enter any spaces, periods, 
5.1.2 or other punctuation after the recipient's email address.    cj9sm2642949wjc.42 - gsmtp
```

Any help please. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send emails to multiple recipients from DB zend 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29431659/send-emails-to-multiple-recipients-from-db-zend-2)

Comment: yes but i do not have an answer that's why i changed on the code and reposted again. Any help please ?

Comment: Your code is correct, you'll get all the email addresses from database. The error you got is an SMTP error : and its clear, it says your recipient email is **not correct**. You have to verify your email addresses.